# When was spontaneous human combustion used for the first time as a plot device in fantasy or science fiction?

Tags: history-of

To many, spontaneous human combustion remains as a myth, making it a prospective plot device in fantasy or science fiction. I am interested to know when was it used for the first time in that way.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_human_combustion#Cultural_references) gives several examples from fiction of the 1840s-1850s but it's not clear the stories belong to the science fiction or fantasy genre.

Comment: Your reference to the Human Torch is confusing, since that _isn't_ an example of spontaneous human combustion.  Do you want the latter, or are you looking for the first appearance of a character who produces flames from their body?

Comment: @DavidW - Thank you for the comment. I want the latter. I will replace my reference.

Comment: @user14111 - To me, it will be enough if the SHC device is used/legitimized within f/sf realm.

Comment: @user14111 - I'm sorry I don't make myself understood. I meant SHC produced, for instance, by fantasy devices (i.e. an incantation, a curse..) or science fiction devices (i.e. an atomic formula, a cosmic power source..).

Comment: Thanks, it's clear now. What's the earliest example you know of, so we know what date we have to beat?

Comment: @user14111 - 
Walter Owen in "More Things in Heaven..." (1947) uses SHC device among Merlin and Alex the Great.

Comment: Not an answer but of possible interest: the 1984 Bob Shaw novel *Fire Pattern* uses SHC as a theme.

Answer (score 1):

the 1977 spoof "documentary" *Alternative 3* talks about "hot jobs", in which, among other things, the British government induces SHC to silence informants. I don't know if it explains exactly how the government does this.

*Alternative 3" has also gotten incorporated into conspiracy theory mythologies as actually real.